# Preserve query string in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` rules:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*/$ /htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ /htcache/index.html [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*\.html$ /htcache/video/$1/$2/$3/$0 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*\/$ /htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0\index.html [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

in this rules if a requested url contain a query string and file is not exist in htcache folder the rewrite rule work but the query string is not executed

request eg `https://www.mywebsite.com/fun-videos/?page=2`
if file exist `/htcache/videos/f/u/n/fun-videos/page=2.html` "file found"

But if file is not present the page `/index.php` is executed without the query string.

some ideas???

Comment: Try using `QSA` flag in your rules. QSA stands for `Query String Append` .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
> RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*/$ /htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L]
> ```

The problem here is that you are rewriting to the "cache file" (and *removing* the query string with the trailing `?`) regardless of whether the cache file exists or not.

It is only when the "cache file" does not exist are you rewriting the already rewritten request (without a query string) to `index.php`.

You should first check that the cached file exists before rewriting to it. Although simply removing the trailing `?` on the first rule will prevent the query string from being removed.

Note also that the *condition* is simply checking whether `page=` is present anywhere in the query string, not strictly that there is a `page` URL parameter - if that matters.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*\/$ /htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0\index.html [L]
> ```

*Aside:* There is no need to backslash-escape the last slash in the *TestString* (first argument) and `\i` in the *substitution* string is just a literal `i` - unless that should really be `/i`?

For example, try it like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*/$ /htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0%{QUERY_STRING}.html? [L]

RewriteRule ^$ /htcache/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/htcache/video/$1/$2/$3/$0 -f
RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*\.html$ /htcache/video/$1/$2/$3/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*/$ /htcache/videos/$1/$2/$3/$0index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

You are not actually using the `RewriteBase` directive here, so I removed it.

Comment: thanks mrwhite but i don't understand .... the rules work only if the cache is empty ... if the page mywebsite.com/fun-videos/ is cached, in "/htcache/videos/f/u/n/fun-videos/index.html",  all the next requested pages with query string return the non query string result

Comment: @remi "the rules work only if the cache is empty" - but in your question you stated: "if file is **not** present the page /index.php is executed **without the query string**". Have you tried the directives in my answer? As stated in my answer, one of the problems with your rules was that you are rewriting to the cache file _unconditionally_, regardless of whether the cache file actually exists or not. When the cache file doesn't exist then the request is rewritten a second time. There should only be one rewrite here.

Comment: @remi Presumably you are wanting to remove the query string when requesting a page from cache when the `page=` URL param is present? Or is the trailing `?` entirely erroneous? (Although I've also mentioned this in my answer.)